# If an area enters lockdown, are the current schemes canceled forever or do they just pause?

Tags: evil-genius-2

If you reach maximum heat in an area, what happens to currently running schemes?

Are they cancel or do they just pause and then they resume when the are leaves lockdown?

Answer (score 1):

Currently running schemes are canceled and you lose all minions working on it and the remaining of the gold/heat reduction on the scheme.

If the scheme is one that has a specific reward, then you don't get anything, so you should calculate the time left for reaching the maximum heat before starting the mission.